# Azure container instance limit value not working as expected

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-instances

[image: Container]

I believe above configuration is right but I get an error in powershell (The 'MemoryInGB' limit value must be greater than or equal to the request value.) and if I give greater value in limits then I get error (The 'MemoryInGB' limit '1.5' in container 'xxx' is greater than the total request '1.1' of container group 'zzz'.)
Let me know if the configuration is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're requesting more memory than the limit allows.  Have you tried reversing them, e.g. requesting 1.1 GiB and setting the limit to 1.5 GiB?

Comment: I did even that.. It is giving another error which I posed in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, currently it only supports the requests and the limits are set with the same value.

> 1. For a container, the limit can't be less than what this same container asked for.
> 2. The limit can't be more than the total resources requested by all containers in the container group.

So I think to set the `limits` is tot very useful. Just set the `requests` block as the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml#configure-a-yaml-file) shows.